# Clean Unique ID's

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, unique, share

**Problem summary:**

We are developing an App and want to give our users an easily memorable ID to share items in a fast fashion.

**Problem detailed:**

We are currently uniquily identifying items by the automatically generated ID's from MongoDB. Unique ID's in MongoDB are long and hard to remember. We would like to give our users easily memorable ID's to easily share items with other users.

For example an element in the App needs to be worked on, telling a colleague to go to ourapp.com/a7wefweg43tr is a pain in the ass, what we would like is to in addition to the unique id to technically identify the element within the app a more human readable / memorable unique id for sharability. (Very similar to what Jira is offering (AA-0001, etc.)

Are there best practices on how to implement this / any JS libraries that would do the job ?

Comment: is your app like Jira? would `ZG-2973` not be just as much a pain to remember as a7wefweg43tr, presuming the pain comes from remembering it if not copy and pasting? Imo the easiest and most convenient for the user is to ask for a username or slug which you implement as unique, like most sites, there is no package for it but its trivial to do.

Comment: a simple idea with tutorial (NodeJs) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLpUKAGnm-g

Answer (score 1):

If you can have a central service that you would call out to to generate unique IDs, do that and in this service implement any pattern for ID generation you like. MongoDB IDs are designed to be generated by non-communicating clients in a manner that is as collision-free as possible.

Answer (score 0):

human-readable and technical unique are on the opposite end of the same road ... why not let the creator of the ticket type in a human-designed short-tag, check if already existing and provide a slightly extended version if already used. like account-creation in online-games.
if no context between item and id is needed ... put in a dictionary of common-words, create a new random tripple of these words, check if already existing, repeat if already used. easy to memorize and tell by phone. like the military spelling alpha-zulu-tango